# appannie API errors : Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#

I am trying to use appannie API but getting alot of errors and after a lot of searching in google I got this error :

```
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

and this is my code :

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string url = "https://api.appannie.com/v1/accounts";



            string token = "***********";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
            //request.WebProxy.GetProxy();
            request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;


            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            }
          }
```

please if you have any idea to help me.

Appannie API details:
http://appannie.zendesk.com/entries/23224068-1-Account-Connections-List

Comment: have you tried giving page index to at the end in url                 api.appannie.com/v1/accounts?page_index=0

Comment: @Bunny The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code working perfectly after a lot of search :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string url = "https://api.appannie.com/v1/accounts?page_index=0";
            string id="",temp="";


            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
            request.ContentType = "Accept: application/xml";
            request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.Referer = "http://stackoverflow.com";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer ***********");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format.
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                temp = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                //TextArea1.InnerText = temp + "\n";
                string[] id_arr = temp.Split(',');
                int count = 0;
                while (count != id_arr.Length)
                {

                    if (id_arr[count].Contains("account_id"))
                    {
                        id = id_arr[count];
                        count = id_arr.Length;
                        break;
                    }

                    count++;
                }
                id = id.Substring(id.IndexOf("account_id") + 13);
                //TextArea1.InnerText += id;


                //Console.Write(readStream.ReadToEnd());
                //response.Close();
                response = null;
                //readStream.Close();
                request = null;

                string date = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                string url2 = "https://api.appannie.com/v1/accounts/" + id + "/sales?break_down=application+date" +
                                            "&start_date="+date+
                                            "&end_date="+date+
                                            "&currency=USD" +
                                            "&countries=" +
                                            "&page_index=0";


                TextArea1.InnerText = url2;


                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url2);
                request.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
                request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                request.Referer = "http://stackoverflow.com";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer ************");
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


                receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format.
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                temp = "";
                temp = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                //TextArea1.InnerText = temp;

                string[] id_arr2 = temp.Split(',');
                int count2 = 0;
                string down = "";
                string update = "";
                while (count2 != id_arr2.Length)
                {

                    if (id_arr2[count2].Contains("downloads"))
                    {
                        down = id_arr2[count2];
                        count2 = id_arr2.Length;
                        break;
                    }

                    count2++;
                }

                count2 = 0;

                while (count2 != id_arr2.Length)
                {

                    if (id_arr2[count2].Contains("update"))
                    {
                        update = id_arr2[count2];
                        count2 = id_arr2.Length;
                        break;
                    }

                    count2++;
                }


                down = down.Substring(down.IndexOf("downloads") + 12);
                update = update.Substring(update.IndexOf("update") + 9);

                //TextArea1.InnerText = "downloads : "+down+ "----- update :" + update;

                TextBox1.Text = down;
                TextBox2.Text = update;


            }
}
```

*** means your API private key.